# How to order custom attribute in Datatable?

Tags: laravel-backpack

Say my User model's `balance` attribute from `getBalanceAttribute()` returns the sum of `amount` from user's Transaction model, how can this be orderable in the Datatable?

`User.php`

```
public function transactions()
{
  return $this->hasMany(\App\Transaction::class);
}

public function getBalanceAttribute()
{
  return $this->transactions()->sum('amount');
}
```

`Transaction.php`

```
public function user()
{
  return $this->belongsTo(\App\User::class);
}
```

`UserCrudController.php`

```
...
public function setup()
{
  ...
  $this->crud->addColumn(
  [
    'name' => "balance",
    'label' => "Balance",
    'type' => 'number',
    // Here the column is clickable but is not actually sorted.
    'orderable' => true,
  ],
  ...
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, Backpack cannot make a `model_function` column orderable, since model functions are called after the SQL has already gotten back.

Sorry.

Comment: Okey. Thanks. I got it resolved thou, with additional column (balance) in my database table (users). So that it is directly sortable. But requires additional database storage and processing just to make an attribute sortable in the Datatable.

Comment: @abacitu So then how to order type model_function or closure in backpack?